# Sequential Complexity for Autoencoder

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, autoencoder

How can I compute the time complexity of the training of an Autoencoder that take in input an array of dimension `1xN` and have only one hidden layer with with `M` neurons. So the matrices of weights are `NxM` for the hidden layer (encoder weights) and `MxN` for the output layer (decoder weights).

For both feed-forward and back-propagatation, igmoid activation function is used.

To study the time complexity, do I have to consider also the number of epochs of the training, or the time complexity is referred to only to a trained NN (Autoencoder in my case)?

Thanks a lot!